# numbers of keys in a hash

Tags: perl

I am trying to find out the number of keys and number of values in a hash and print those numbers. I've written my code like this but it has not given the number of keys. What is the error in my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;
my $file;open $file, 'formal.xml');
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( IO => $file ) or die ("unable to open file");

while ( $reader->nextElement( 'DATA' ) ) {
    my $info = $reader->readOuterXml();
    $reader->nextElement( 'Number' ); 
    my $number = $reader->readInnerXml(); 
    print( "num: $number\n" );
    print( " datainfo: $info\n" );
```

How can I store these num and datainfo in a hash? And how can I count number of keys in hash? I tried like this but it is not working.

```
my %nums =( "$number", $info);

while ((my $keys, my $values) = each (%nums)) { 
    print ("NUMBER:$keys." =>"INFORMATION: ".$values." \n");
}

my $key_count = keys %nums;
print "$key_count";
} 
close($file);
}
```

When I am trying to execute it, it gives only one number, but I have more numbers. Maybe my hash contains one number, but how can I iterate my hash to store more numbers?

Comment: can you provide example of the inpit data?

Comment: Wait you reinitialized the hash inside the reader while loop? Enumerate it's contents in the same loop too? This is confusing. It doesn't sound like these problems have anything to do with your question, but they are causing you to not get the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
my %nums;
while ( $reader->nextElement( 'DATA' ) ) {     
   my $info = $reader->readOuterXml();     
   $reader->nextElement( 'number' );      
   my $number = $reader->readInnerXml();  
   $nums{$number} = $info;    
   print( "num: $number\n" );    
   print( " datainfo: $info\n" ); 
}
```

and remove `my %nums =( "$number", $info);`

When you do your while loop, your $number and $info overwrite themselves each time. So you need to store that data in the hash in the while loop.

Comment: i tried as above and i removed the line as you said and after i removed my second while loop also then it printing each number and info after that displaying number of key in hash every time it incrementing. like 1,2,3,....141. is there any posibility to print total number of keys is 141 like that, not incrementing 1 to 141. and also if put my second while loop it excuting infinity times continously there is no output.@Andrey

Comment: Can you provide example of input data, output you are getting and the desired output?

Answer (score 7):

`keys()` and `values()` both return arrays.  When referenced in scalar context, arrays in Perl return the size of the array.  So, to get the number of keys or values in your hash, just reference the result of `keys()` or `values()` in scalar context:

```
# prints the number of keys
print( scalar(keys(%hash)), "\n" );
print( keys(%hash) . "\n" );

# prints the number of values
print( scalar(values(%hash)), "\n" );
print( values(%hash) . "\n");
```

Using your `%nums` array:

```
my %nums = ( $number, $info );
print( "number of keys: ", scalar(keys(%nums)), "\n" ); # will print `1'
```

Note that your `%nums` hash has only one key-value pair with `$number` as the key and `$info` as the value.  (A more conventional and readable way to declare `%nums` would be `my %nums = ( $number => $info );` )

Comment: you are write in my hash %nums i have only one element, so how can i iterate more numbers in the same hash, to sotre all values in my hash.

Comment: Here's an example: `for my $num (1..10) { $nums{$num} = "info$num" }`.

`%nums` would now look like this: `( 1 => 'info1', 2 => 'info2', ...)`.  Then to see how many keys you have: `print scalar(keys(%nums))` (will print `10`)

Answer (score 1):

> **Goal:** I am trying to find out numbers keys and number of values in hash.

Here is a direct answer to this question in general.

To obtain the number of **keys** in your hash, apply the `keys` function in a scalar context:

```
scalar keys %my_hash
# -or-
my $number_of_keys = keys %my_hash;
```

The number of **values** will be identical (although one or more values may be undefined). You can prove this by applying the `values` function in a similar fashion:

```
scalar values %my_hash
# -or-
my $number_of_values = values %my_hash;
```